# PHPExcel: Unable to Print Dynamic Row and Column in Php?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi while exporting **Dynmaic row** and Column only columns exported not row,  giving a `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/excel/excelv1.php:615) in /var/www/html/excel/excelv1.php on line 625` error to find out

Error - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIBoa.png)

Here is my code

For **Dynamic Column code** its working fine

```
  $out_table = '';
    $k = 0;
    mysql_data_seek($query_result1, 0);
    $col = 36;
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query_result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, trim($labels[$k] . " (value1)", ','));
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col + 1, 1, trim($labels[$k] . " (value2)", ','));
        $col = $col + 2;
        $k++;
    }

    echo $out_table;
```

Here is **Dynamic Row Code** Which is **not Working**

```
      $inn_table = "";
    if($result['qualification']['dd1']!="") {
            $dd1 = explode(",",$result['qualification']['dd1']);
        }
        if($result['qualification']['dd2']!=""){
            $dd2 = explode(",",$result['qualification']['dd2']);
        }
        for($i=0;$i<count($labels);$i++) {
            if($result['qualification']['dd1']!="") {
                $found=false;
                for($j=0;$j<count($dd1);$j++) {
                    $temp = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);    


                    if($temp[0]==$labels[$i]) {
                        $name = explode(">",$dd1[$j]);
                        $inn_table .= '<td>'.$name[1].'</td>';
                        $found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: First of all stop using `MYSQL` and convert code to `MYSQLI`, next which error do you have?

Comment: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/excel/excelv1.php:615) in /var/www/html/excel/excelv1.php on line 625` this error i am getting

Comment: Can you edit you question with your output code?

Comment: Which is line 625, or any of the others with the error? The error message suggests you are calling the PHP `header()` function but have already sent output to the browser, therefore the headers cannot be modified.

Comment: Suugest me a PHPExcel format to print @droopsnoot

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. I was trying to suggest why you might be getting these error messages.

Comment: I already know all these error mate! @droopsnoot

Comment: Oh, sorry, that seemed to be what your question was. Perhaps you could re-phrase it.